# How to understand the lifetime annotation on impl?

Tags: rust, lifecycle

I have a piece of Rust code.

```
struct ImportantExcerpt<'a> {
    part: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> ImportantExcerpt<'a> {
    fn announce_and_return_part<'b, 'c>(&'c self, announcement: &'b str) -> &'c str {
        println!("Attention please: {}", announcement);
        self.part
    }
}
```

My question about this code is, what is the difference or connection between a and c? What does the lifetime annotation on impl represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `'a` is the lifetime of the reference contained in the `ImportantExceprt` received via `self`.
- `'b` is the lifetime of the additional string slice passed into the method.
- `'c` is the lifetime of the reference to the object the method was called on.

So `'a` and `'b` are different lifetimes of different objects, there is no connection between them.

Since `self` contains a reference of lifetime `'a` but is behind a reference of lifetime `'c`, `'a` has to outlive `'c` (implicit `'a: 'c`), since shared references are covariant in their lifetime we can shorten the lifetime of the returned reference to `'c`

The `<'a>` on the impl simply declares a new lifetime you can use, and it's used to give the lifetime `ImportantExcerpt` receives a name. Since you don't use it further you could as well remove it and use the anonymous lifetime instead:

```rust
impl ImportantExcerpt<'_> {
```

Comment: I understand now, you're very nice.